# Deploy sails.js app in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sails.js

I installed NodeJS and sails in my EC2 server and used `sails lift` with no errors.

When I'm trying to access `PUBLIC_IP:1337`, I get `ERR_CONNECTION_TIME OUT` message.

I also added the following inbound rule to a new security group:
[image]

Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Did you add the new security group to the EC2 instance?

Comment: @sgress454 I mentioned in in my question..

Comment: No, you didn't.  You said you added the rule to a new security group.  I'm just verifying that you actually added the new security group to your EC2 instance.